# Set recyclerview item background color repeatedly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter

I am trying to set different background color in `cardview` but it's not working
I have color array that contain color

```
public class DashboardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<DashboardAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<String> leavetypeList;
    private List<String> leavebalanceList;

    public String[] mColors = {
            "3F51B5","FF9800","009688","673AB7"
    };


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView leavecount,leavename;
        public ImageView thumbnail;
        public RelativeLayout rlauthor;
        CardView cardView;
        View viewline;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            leavecount = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvleavenumber);
            leavename = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvleavetype);
            cardView=(CardView) view.findViewById(R.id.cdvdashboard);
        }
    }

    public DashboardAdapter(Context context, List<String> leavetypeList,List<String> leavebalanceList) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.leavetypeList = leavetypeList;
        this.leavebalanceList = leavebalanceList;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.raw_dashboard, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        Typeface tf;
        tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "fonts/HKNova-Medium.ttf");
        holder.leavecount.setTypeface(tf);
        holder.leavename.setTypeface(tf);

        holder.leavecount.setText(leavebalanceList.get(position));
        holder.leavename.setText(leavetypeList.get(position));

        String color="#"+mColors[position];

        for(int c=1;c<mColors.length;c++)
        {

            holder.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));

            if(c==mColors.length)
            {
                 c=1;
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return leavetypeList.size();
    }
}
```

I want this type of output but only getting the last color and if color finish than show other item background color start from color[0] position

Any help would be highly appreciated

[image]

Comment: show your adapter code, or set your color from adapter

Comment: I am already set color from adapter but not colors are not repeating

Comment: share your code first

Comment: check my edited question

Comment: well you got your answer below, use it in place of "for"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It will not work like that. You need to put this logic inside `onBindViewHolder` where you can change color with help of `position`.
Use like

```
public String[] mColors = {"#3F51B5","#FF9800","#009688","#673AB7"};

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(mColors[position % 4])); // 4 can be replaced by mColors.length
}
```

And look how I redefined mColors array with `#` prefixed. So you need to add # while calculating colors.

Comment: Your answer is working "position % 4" 4 is color array size?

Comment: @MiteshMakwana yes it is. Better you can use `mColors.length` for any size of array

Answer (score 0):

In this case you match some value then set color like this way..
below code add into adapter class..

```
   @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ItemViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    // below code handle click event on recycler view item.
    final String data = mStringList.get(position);
    if (data=="RED")
    {
       // put your logic to set color into card view.
        holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(color));
    }
    holder.textView.setText(data);
    holder.firstButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onItemClick.getPosition(data); // shared data.
        }
    });



}
```